# Dropbox API: Upload a File to Root directory for app with Full Dropbox

Tags: file-upload, root, dropbox-api

I created a Dropbox App with:

- Status: Development
- Permission type: Full Dropbox

Using the [Dropbox API Explorer /upload](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#file_requests_update), I had made a request to upload a file:

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [** ACCESS_TOKEN **]' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
  --header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"","mode":{".tag":"overwrite"},"autorename":true,"mute":false}' \
  --data-binary @'banana.png'
```

The error response:

```
Error: 400
Error in call to API function "files/upload": HTTP header "Dropbox-API-Arg": path: The root folder is unsupported.
```

I would like to understand, is uploading any file to the root directory is not allowed?

I appreciate any feedback, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When uploading a file to Dropbox using the Dropbox API, you can upload to the root folder, but the `path` that you supply for the upload needs to include the desired file name.

So, instead of `""`, you would supply a value like `"/banana.png"`.

(Your use of the filename in `@'banana.png'` is only for telling `curl` which local file to use. That filename there doesn't get sent to Dropbox.)